# Connecting docker client to remote docker daemon over TLS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssl, docker

### What I would like

I've installed docker on an Ubuntu (14.04) box by following [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#adjust-memory-and-swap-accounting).

I would like to do whatever configuration is necessary to **securely** connect to the docker daemon on this box from my laptop running OSX.

```
# on my OSX laptop
$ docker ps
# lists docker containers running on my Ubuntu box
```

### What I've tried

I have already [enabled UFW forwarding](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#enable-ufw-forwarding) (and set the port to `2376` since I am using TLS) and followed the [instructions to protect the docker daemon socket via TLS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

I ran the `openssl` commands on my Ubuntu box since OSX is notorious for coming with a bad version of `openssl`. I then copied over (via `scp`) `ca.pem`, `cert.pem` and `key.pem` to my OSX laptop at `~/.docker`.

I then `sudo service docker stop` and `docker daemon --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376` on my Ubuntu box.

Lastly on OSX I made sure to set the relevant docker environment variables:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$HOST:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.docker
```

However, I keep getting `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?` a couple seconds after running `docker ps` on my laptop.

One doubt I have is whether the [TLS instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) are meant for **remote** access at all, as the code shown seems to all be run on 1 machine.

Comment: are you able to open a socker from osx to that port on the linux box? what does `nc -vz $HOST 2376` show?